# PhoneGap offline event fires too slow

Tags: cordova, events, offline

In my PhoneGap app I first check if the device is connected to the internet before running code and calling an API etc.

```
if (window.navigator.onLine == false) {
    //error handling
} else {
    //do stuff & call API
}
```

This perfectly works, but if the device loses it's connection and the page is reloaded WITHIN 5 seconds or so after I diconnected, the code still fires and the API is called although the device is not connected anymore. If the page is reloaded AFTER approximately 5 seconds the error handling is fired as expected.

So it looks like it takes up to approximately 5 seconds after the connection is lost to change to "offline". I double checked this with the offline event and it was only fired after those 5 seconds.

```
document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

function onOffline() {
    alert("now offline");
}
```

So is there a way to check immediately when the connection is lost or being deactived or something?

Comment: Odd - I've never seen such a long delay, but, in theory, you should still be using an error handler for your network calls and handling errors there as well. This really sounds device specific to me though.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. It's just that with the network call (timeout) errors there is an option for users to try again which then becomes pointless since there's no actual connection. So they can try again.. forever.

Comment: On the device specific thing: just tested on iOS simulator and event is fired almost immediately, on iPad 3 and iPhone 6 fired after 6 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

If the issue is specifically with checking online status directly at page load, use the network-information plugin and call a function directly after page load completes:

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = false;
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = true;
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = true;
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = true;
    states[Connection.NONE]     = false;
    return states[networkState];
}
```

The `offline` and `online` events work specifically once the application is in use. The network-information plugin can return connection status as soon as the `deviceready` event is fired.

Comment: Tried with network-information plugin and check if "navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE" . Still a 5 seconds gap before disconnection is noticed.

Comment: with iOS you really need the check for `UNKNOWN` as well. I tried to find the document that explains this, but couldn't remember where I found it.

Comment: Tried that, still a 5 seconds gap. Guess it's device specific since there is no gap on the iOS simulator.